# Custom Report Printing in Oracle Apex

Tags: printing, report, oracle-apex

What is the best way to create a Custom Report Template to print in Oracle Apex ? I saw some posts that've already been answered, but since they were Apex 5.1, I was wondering if these were still up to date, or if there are easier way no (I am using Apex v21.1). Also, the "Printing" attribute in the Reports does not give me the possiblities to do these specific things :

I would like the users to print an Interactive Report, which will display the logo of the company, the export date, and the data obviously. Is it possible to set custom margin so the list take more space on the page, and to set a custom size for the column, in case I have a column with a long text in it ?

Thanks in advance,

Thomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to one of the weakest points of Oracle APEX, printing.

Honestly, the best option is Apex Office Print(AOP), but they are a paid plugin.

They enable lots of different printing, quite easy to grasp, and I am quite satisfied with them.

Other options I have seen are:

Make an excel sheet from within the database and you can generate that dynamically(you can also expand fields, colour them, probably can also put an image in there but I havent tried that).

I once decided to torture myself and I tried printing through HTML, as in I created an HTML document with the data I wanted(I made an invoice), but that has many problems, chief among them being page breaks.

Another option that was recommended to me, but that I have not yet tried was setting up an Apache FOP, having the Oracle database generate an XML, send it there and get back a nice looking pdf(http://www.apex-reports.com/videos.html).

I hope you get something working, and if you try this Apache FOP approach please let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I now understand why there are just a few tutorials for custom printing, since it looks like a weak point in Apex. I will try to go more in depth with your informations.

Comment: Weak because they're concentrating on a data driven web based solution, where printing is a subjective requirement. Agreed that AOP is the best alternative.

Comment: IIRC even Oracle themselves use AOP